# make dynamic tab on createMaterialTopTabNavigator of react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making the top tab navigator using createMaterialTopTabNavigator of react-navigation. The problem I faced is that **the tabs have to decide by the response data of API request.** For example, I call an API to request the football team list, receive the list and then set the tabs of the `MaterialTopTabNvigator`.

I already make the label of the navigator using the component like following :

```js
class TabBarLabel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.focused ? (
      <View style={lstyles.container_focused}>
        <Text style={lstyles.label_focused}>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <View style={lstyles.container_blur}>
        <Text style={lstyles.label_blur}>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const FootballTeamNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    teamA : {
      screen: AScreenComponent,
      navigationOptions: () => {
        return {
          title: 'teamA',
          tabBarLabel({focused}) {
            return <TabBarLabel focused={focused} name="teamA" />;
          }
        };
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: teamA,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    timingConfig: {
      duration: 1000,
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      scrollEnabled: true,
      ...styles,
    },
  },
);
```

What I want to do is like :

```js
let teamList = {};

apiForGetFootballTeamList().then(response => {
  for (const team of response.data.list) {
    tempList[team.name] = team;
  }
});

createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    ...teamList
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: ...,
    ...
  }
);
```

But I don't know how can I update the tabs using data, like component. (component has state and if we update the state, the component is updated)

Is there any way for it?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your problem, any tutorial on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of React Navigation don't support dynamic configuration. You need to use React navigation 5 for that https://blog.expo.io/announcing-react-navigation-5-0-bd9e5d45569e

Comment: Thanks, then there is no tricky way though? I think many people think about this issue...

Comment: The architecture relies on static configuration. React Navigation 5 is a complete rewrite because the old architecture didn't support dynamic configuration.

Comment: any tutorial on how to do so ? because I am really interested in the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Got to a couple of different threads trying to do this (this one among others). Did not manage to find a solution, but in the end it ended up being rather easy.

```
<Tab.Navigator>
            {villages.map(village => (
                <Tab.Screen
                    key={village.villageId}
                    name={village.name}
                    component={ResourceFieldScreen}
                    initialParams={{ village: village }}
                />
            ))}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

At the top, before the function itself I have:

`const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();`

In this case screens are created based on how many counts of `village` there are in `villages`. Then a prop of `village` is sent to the component that is supposed to render it all `ResourceFieldScreen`. Which makes it possible to show whatever is included in `villages`, on that screen.

Code for that part:

```
function ResourceFieldScreen({ route }) {
  const village = route.params.village;
```